# Excel: matching value in table then returning value of specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

```
userID                Payment
--------------------------------------
1                     5000
2                     2489
3                     2529
4                     7423
3                     4328
5                     6475
1                     5644
1                     8585
2                     3214
5                     9876
```

and I have already gathered all the distinct userIDs and copied them to a new area

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'd like a formula I can put next to the distinct user ids that will search the 1st table, match userIDs and gather a sum of the payment values... So my distinct userids table would end up looking like this

```
userID        Payment
1             19229
2             5703
3             6857
4             7423
5             16351
```

I'm guessing i'm looking for something with vlookup, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMIF`, like this (userID in `A:A`, Payments in `B:B`)

```
=SUMIF(A:A,D1,B:B)
```